# Show 2 random li's on from ul - PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, random

Hoping someone can help.

I'm building a wordpress site and as part of the design, I've got some 'feature panels' that I'd like to show.

There's a total of 4 li's in the list - but I'd only like to show 2 random ones on every page.

I can do it via CSS by showing / hiding each li based on the page's class - however I'm wondering whether there's a more elegant way of doing the same via PHP?

My HTML is here... I have no idea where to start with the PHP and it seems that I'm Googling the wrong keywords...

```
    <ul id="featurePanels">
  <li id="newBoatsPanel">
    <h3><a href="#">New Boats<br />
      <span>Text</span></a></h3>
  </li>
  <li id="brokeragePanel">
    <h3><a href="#">Brokerage<br />
      <span>Text</span></a></h3>
  </li>
  <li id="newsPanel">
    <h3><a href="#">News<br />
      <span>Text</span></a></h3>
  </li>
  <li id="partsPanel">
    <h3><a href="#">Parts<br />
      <span>Need text here</span></a></h3>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Please define elegant. I'd say that CSS is pretty elegant here.

Comment: If I have 20 pages on my site, I have to write 20 different rules to show / hide certain panels and this is based on me dictating which panels to show on which pages - which essentially isn't random at all. If PHP can do the same in a few lines of code, then it seems like a more elegant solution - in my opinion anyhow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

$listItems = array(
 '<li id="newBoatsPanel">your text here</li>',
 '<li id="brokeragePanel">more text here</li>',
 '<li id="newsPanel">text text text</li>',
 '<li id="partsPanel">Need text here</li>'
);

shuffle($listItems); // shuffles (randomizes the order of the elements)

// print the list
echo '<ul id="featurePanels">' . $listItems[0] . $listItems[1] . '</ul>';

?>
```

Comment: Hi - thanks. This looks like it's the kind of thing I'm after, however when adding the code to the site I get the following error "Warning: shuffle() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in"

Comment: be sure to pass `$listItems` as parameter in `shuffle()`. And the `$listItems` array must exist.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 
`preg_match_all('/\<li.*?\>.*?\</li\>/i',$html_string,$li_list)`

in $li_list you will have an array of li's and now you can shuffle, random, splice, slice or whatever...

and at the end use `implode` to get the HTML.